# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/api/DataTable error while rinning cucmber tests

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am trying to run cucumber test with cucmber version 4.1.0 but I see the following error -

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/api/DataTable

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:82)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.<init>(Runner.java:28)
    at cucumber.runner.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.createRunner(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:44)
    at cucumber.runner.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.access$000(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:15)
    at cucumber.runner.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:24)
    at cucumber.runner.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier$1.initialValue(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:21)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at cucumber.runner.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.get(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:40)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.DataTable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 29 more
```

Here is my POM file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
  <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
  <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
  <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

where:
4.1.0

None of my step definition files have any errors, I have imported all my datatable code as io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable. Can somebody please help what could have gone wrong. there are cucumber spring dependency that i am using.

Comment: do you have cucumber-core on the dependency?

Comment: I do not have cucumber core dependency.i am guessing it is a transient dependency that is causing this problem.

Comment: Are you importing any dependencies that use `cucumber.api.Datatable`?

Comment: Fixed this problem there were some transient dependencies. thank you.